# To create a chaser box game area with nested loop for 2 dimension array only outputs 1 row of squares

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a simple chaser box game, but I really stuck on the gameArea squares, I wanna make a 3*8 squares of gameArea, but it only create 1*24 squares.

I have tried to only use gameArea width to make a horizontal array of squares but it outputs 24 squares vertically, I also changed width to right for the gamebox, but still remains the same output. Here is my code:

```js
let box = {};
const score = document.querySelector(".score");
const gameAreaEle = document.querySelector(".gameArea");
const gameArea = gameAreaEle.getBoundingClientRect();
let squares = [];
let gamebox = {
  x: Math.floor(gameArea.width / 100),
  y: Math.floor(gameArea.height / 100)
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", build);

function build() {
  box = document.createElement("div");
  box.classList.add("box");
  box.x = gameArea.top;
  box.y = gameArea.left;
  box.style.top = box.y + "px";
  box.style.left = box.x + "px";
  gameAreaEle.appendChild(box);
  let counter = 1;
  for (let y = 0; y < gamebox.y; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < gamebox.x; x++) {
      squares[counter] = document.createElement("div");
      squares[counter].innerHTML = counter;
      squares[counter].classList.add("square");
      gameAreaEle.appendChild(squares[counter]);
      counter++;
    }
  }
  console.log(box);
}
```

```css
.gameArea {
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
}

.score {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 98px;
  height: 98px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ddd;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gameArea"></div>
  <div>Score :<span class="score">0</span></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I expect to output 3*8 squares in the game area is someone got a thought about it, I just confused.

Comment: Maybe you can use a html list with css so each ul is designed as a square ?

Comment: @axelaxel Thanks axel, but this is not what I actually want to achieve, the box that declared will move and catch the target square, so I don't really think html and css do the trick.

Comment: i know thtat i was just giving you a hint about the visual but then you use javascript to move inside the table with your squares but np if you had found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I had to reduce the dimensions of your example to make it fit in the visible area of my reduced browser

but the corner stone is the `display:block` vs `display:inline-block`

for reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

```js
let box = {};
const score = document.querySelector(".score");
const gameAreaEle = document.querySelector(".gameArea");
const gameArea = gameAreaEle.getBoundingClientRect();
let squares = [];
let gamebox = {
  x: Math.floor(gameArea.width / 50),
  y: Math.floor(gameArea.height / 50)
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", build);

function build() {
  box = document.createElement("div");
  box.classList.add("box");
  box.x = gameArea.top;
  box.y = gameArea.left;
  box.style.top = box.y + "px";
  box.style.left = box.x + "px";
  gameAreaEle.appendChild(box);
  let counter = 1;
  for (let y = 0; y < gamebox.y; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < gamebox.x; x++) {
      squares[counter] = document.createElement("div");
      squares[counter].innerHTML = counter;
      squares[counter].classList.add("square");
      gameAreaEle.appendChild(squares[counter]);
      counter++;
    }
  }
  console.log(box);
}
```

```css
.gameArea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}

.score {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  display: inline-block; /* <== */
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ddd;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gameArea"></div>
  <div>Score :<span class="score">0</span></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, this is actually work, the inline-block allows me to create multiple squares (or blocks) in a line! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

your squares should be displayed as inline-block and not block, and reduce width of your game area to 300px so that you get 3 boxes on each row, and make your height 800 px so that you get 3x8 boxes

```js
let box = {};
const score = document.querySelector(".score");
const gameAreaEle = document.querySelector(".gameArea");
const gameArea = gameAreaEle.getBoundingClientRect();
let squares = [];
let gamebox = {
  x: Math.floor(gameArea.width / 100),
  y: Math.floor(gameArea.height / 100)
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", build);

function build() {
  box = document.createElement("div");
  box.classList.add("box");
  box.x = gameArea.top;
  box.y = gameArea.left;
  box.style.top = box.y + "px";
  box.style.left = box.x + "px";
  gameAreaEle.appendChild(box);
  let counter = 1;
  for (let y = 0; y < gamebox.y; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < gamebox.x; x++) {
      squares[counter] = document.createElement("div");
      squares[counter].innerHTML = counter;
      squares[counter].classList.add("square");
      gameAreaEle.appendChild(squares[counter]);
      counter++;
    }
  }
  console.log(box);
}
```

```css
.gameArea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 800px;
}

.score {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 98px;
  height: 98px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ddd;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gameArea"></div>
  <div>Score :<span class="score">0</span></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, the inline-block do the job for me, didn't realize that inline-block has so much differentiation with block.

Comment: Yeah the main difference is that no element can be placed in the same line of a block, but for inline-block it can be done, if you want to read more about it this link will help you https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

Answer (score 1):

I commented out your box element. I don't know what it is but you can just set background color to the existing block if you want it.

What I added to make it into 3 column is

1. add `float: left;` into the `square` class.
2. add `.square:nth-child(3n+1) {
     clear: left;
   }`

to make it into 3 column by clearing every 3 `.square` nodes.

```js
let box = {};
const score = document.querySelector(".score");
const gameAreaEle = document.querySelector(".gameArea");
const gameArea = gameAreaEle.getBoundingClientRect();
let squares = [];
let gamebox = {
  x: Math.floor(gameArea.width / 100),
  y: Math.floor(gameArea.height / 100)
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", build);

function build() {
  /*
  box = document.createElement("div");
  box.classList.add("box");
  box.x = gameArea.top;
  box.y = gameArea.left;
  box.style.top = box.y + "px";
  box.style.left = box.x + "px";
  gameAreaEle.appendChild(box);
  */
  let counter = 1;
  for (let y = 0; y < gamebox.y; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < gamebox.x; x++) {
      squares[counter] = document.createElement("div");
      squares[counter].innerHTML = counter;
      squares[counter].classList.add("square");
      gameAreaEle.appendChild(squares[counter]);
      counter++;
    }
  }
  console.log(box);
}
```

```css
.gameArea {
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
}

.score {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 98px;
  height: 98px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ddd;
}

.square:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: left;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gameArea"></div>
  <div>Score :<span class="score">0</span></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was inline-block nailed it!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem resides inside your `for loops`. You have `two` for loops. What you might want to do is to create a `outDiv` inside your first for loop in each iteration. So There will be three `outDiv` as you want to create a `3x8` matrix. Each `outDiv` must have css property `float:left` and each `outDiv` must be be appended in `gameArea` div And inside the inner for loop you have to create eight inDiv. All of the `inDiv` must be appended in the respective `outDiv`.Each `inDiv` must have css property `display:inline-block`.Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79dags2q/)

**code :**

```
let counter = 1;
for(let y = 1; y<=gamebox.y; y++){

    let outDiv = document.createElement("div")
    outDiv.style.width = 830+"px"
    outDiv.style.height = 100 +"px"
    outDiv.style.float = "left"

  for(let x = 1; x<=gamebox.x; x++){
          let inDiv = document.createElement("div");
          inDiv.innerHTML = counter;
          inDiv.style.width = 100+"px"
          inDiv.style.height = 100+"px"
          inDiv.style.border = "1px solid black"
          inDiv.style.display = "inline-block"
           outDiv.appendChild(inDiv)
          counter++;
        }
    gameAreaEle.appendChild(outDiv);
}
```